# Problem saving ENUM field to MySQL using symfony1.4/Doctrine using jquery ajax call

Tags: mysql, ajax, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I'm currently on a project that receives applications and the part I'm currently on has a grader that assigns a manual grade for the application.  The possible scores are enum values stored in a MySQL field.  For whatever reason I cannot seem to get the value to actually be save to the database.

I have tried Doctrines Rawsql and I have tried the method below (that I would expect to work).  I have done testing to ensure that the values received on the server side to match the SQL enum field.  I've tried to include as much code as possible that I see as pertaining to the issue, but if there's more needed just let me know!

Function to update field in DB.

```
public function executeSetLongAnswerGrade(sfWebRequest $request){

    $application = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        if($request->getParameter("methodCall") == "Passion"){
            $application->setGradepassion($request->getParameter('value'));
            return true;
        }elseif($request->getParameter("methodCall") == "Grammer"){
            $application->setGradegrammer($request->getParameter('value'));

        }elseif($request->getParameter('methodCall') == "Thought"){
            $application->setGradethought($request->getParameter('value'));
            return true;
        }
        $application->save();
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

Route:

```
ajaxSetLongAnswerGrade:
  url:          /setLongAnswerGrade/:applicationId
  class:        sfDoctrineRoute
  options:      { model: Application, type: object}
  param:        { module: application, action: SetLongAnswerGrade } 
  requirements: 
    id:         \d+ 
    sf_method:  [get]
```

---

Ajax Call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#passionMSG').hide();
$('#grammerMSG').hide();
$('#thoughtMSG').hide();
$('.passionSuccess').hide();$('.passionError').hide();
$('.grammerSuccess').hide();$('.grammerError').hide();
$('.thoughtSuccess').hide();$('.thoughtError').hide();
$('#passion').change(function()
{
    $('#passion').attr('disabled', true);
            $('.passionSuccess').hide();
            $('#passionMSG').slideDown(200);
            $('.passionError').hide();
    $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo url_for2('ajaxSetLongAnswerGrade', $application) ?>',
          data: { methodCall: "Passion",
                              value: this.value} ,
          success: function(data) {
              $('#passion').attr('disabled', false);
                              $('#passionMSG').slideUp(1500)
                              $('.passionSuccess').delay(1300).slideDown(2000);
          },
                      error: function(){
                              $('#passion').attr('disabled', false);
                              $('#passionMSG').slideUp(1500)
                              $('.passionError').delay(1300).slideDown(2000);
                      }
        });
});});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This ended up being in my routing.yml file.  The lack of `method: find` in `options:      { model: Application, type: object}`is what was causing the error.  A save was occuring, but not on the record I was wanting (I thought this was implicit but it instantly started working after I added this). final code...

```
public function executeSetLongAnswerGrade(sfWebRequest $request){
$application = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
    $application->{$request->getParameter('value')}($request->getParameter('value'));
    $application->save();
    return sfView::NONE;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

and the ajax....

```
$('#passion').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.passionSuccess').hide();
        $('#passionMSG').slideDown(200);
        $('.passionError').hide();
$.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo url_for2('ajaxSetLongAnswerGrade', $application) ?>',
      data: { methodCall: "setGradepassion",
                          value: this.value} ,
      success: function(data) {
          $('#passion').attr('disabled', false);
                          $('#passionMSG').slideUp(1500)
                          $('.passionSuccess').delay(1300).slideDown(2000);
      },
                  error: function(){
                          $('#passion').attr('disabled', false);
                          $('#passionMSG').slideUp(1500)
                          $('.passionError').delay(1300).slideDown(2000);
                  }
    });
```

I do appreciate the guidance!  I was raised Java and still getting used to symfony/php.

Comment: And why the down-vote?  If you are going to down-vote at least be man/woman enough to explain why... ESPECIALLY on such an old post...

Answer (score 1):

When you use `return` in ana action it sends the response... you have `return` in each of your conditions but you arent calling `$application->save();` first.

Elimintate the returns, or call save before each return:

```
public function executeSetLongAnswerGrade(sfWebRequest $request){

    $application = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        if($request->getParameter("methodCall") == "Passion"){

            $application->setGradepassion($request->getParameter('value'));

        }elseif($request->getParameter("methodCall") == "Grammer"){

            $application->setGradegrammer($request->getParameter('value'));

        }elseif($request->getParameter('methodCall') == "Thought"){

            $application->setGradethought($request->getParameter('value'));
        }

        $application->save();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I Would also probably revise this logic to:

```
public function executeSetLongAnswerGrade(sfWebRequest $request)
{
   $application = $this->getRoute()->getObject();

   if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
   {
      $call = $request->getParameter('methodCall');
      $value = $request->getParameter('value');

      switch($call)
      {
         case 'Passion':
           $application->setGradepassion($value);
           break;
         case 'Grammer':
           $application->setGradegrammer($value);
           break;
         case 'Thought':
           $application->setGradethought($value);
           break;
         default:
           throw new Exception('Invalid methodCall.');
      }

      $application->save();

      return sfView::NONE;

   }
}
```

Comment: I'm 90% positive this is how my original logic was coded (I believe I tried two things......) 
1: 
`return $application->save();` 
(knowing that save has a void return) 
2: 
`$application->save(); return true;`

The code in the post was done to double check the values being sent to server (wanted to make sure that values received were indeed what the enum fields in the db were)  When I get back to work in the AM I'll up date my post with the correct code and I'm sorry for the mixup.  The logic is not final either I just want to get the save functioning and then I'll iron it out.

Comment: Well you should be returning a template name... normally you can jsut return true/false because after that the view renderer sets the response value assuming that the return is part of a template name in the form `actionnameTemplatename.php` in that modules directory returning `true` should result in trying to render `setLongAnswerGrade1.php` which should throw an exception and 500 status code.

Comment: I'll be sure and switch the return type tomorrow.  Still fairly new to symfony so wasn't aware of needing the view returned on an ajax call.  I appreciate the guidance so far!

Comment: @jared: thats whay i returned `sfView::NONE` it skips the view rendering. There are some other predefined constants like that and for just sending headers and some other things take a look at the `sfView` class.